# How do I get Update-Help to download the help documentation for PowerShell on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, powershell

I installed PowerShell on Ubuntu 18.04.2 running in WSL 2. I would like to use PowerShell as my default shell. I noticed that when I try use `Get-Help` on any topic it says help documents were not found and to use `Update-Help` to get them. This works on regular Windows PowerShell just fine, but on Ubuntu `Update-Help` doesn't update anything. I continue to not have documentation for any commands. Is it not possible to get docs for PowerShell on Ubuntu? Do I have to switch to Windows to read the docs or search online? I would prefer if it all worked like it usually does on Windows PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Not all that works on Windows PowerShell, will work with PowerShell Core on Windows/OSX/*Nix by design and vice versa. They are two separate environments, with separate codebases, etc...

I'm a Windows type, but, I've not had this issue on OSX/*Nix (kali).

But the Update-Help cmdlet does work on Ubuntu, see this article and instructions (snippet above) ...

> https://linuxhint.com/install_powershell_ubuntu

... and if it is not on yours, then this is an environmental thing on your side.

It's been asked before, and though you are using your flavor of *Nix, try...

https://www.kali.org/tutorials/installing-powershell-on-kali-linux

... or the ...

> Use the Save-Help cmdlet to download help files from the Internet and
>   save them in a file system location, such as a shared folder or file
>   system directory. Then use the SourcePath parameter of Update-Help to
>   get the updated help files from a file system location and install
>   them on the computer.
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/save-help?view=powershell-6
>
> Please refer to the section HOW TO UPDATE HELP FROM A FILE SHARE:
>   SAVE-HELP Of the link to get help with downloading and installing the
>   update-help files.
>
> [About Updatable Help](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_updatable_help?view=powershell-6)
>
> Also, refer to the HELP FILES FOR MODULES section to know how to
>   update help files for individual modules.

***Point of note:***

Windows, Linux, OSX, regardless, many of the help files are not updateable for various reasons. So, when you see those errors, just ignore them, because there is nothing you'll be able to do to fix it, as it is up to the authors.